# Xcode won't open any projects

Tags: xcode

I have been searching and going through many other similar questions but none of them seem to solve my solution. I am trying to open up an Xcode project but after the menu launches and I click on a project, it just loads forever until I have to force it to quit. I have tried to remove the derived data and uninstalling and reinstalling it again but nothing works. I am currently using Xcode 10.3 on macOS Catalina 10.15 beta. I am also seeing this issue when I install Xcode 11 beta 5.

Comment: I have a similar problem. When launching a project, Xcode crashes. This started happening when I upgraded to the latest Catalina 10.15 Beta a few days ago. I sent bug reports to Apple for MacOS and for Xcode.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23704616)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23704616)

Answer (score 1):

I faced the almost same problem, every time I was trying to open my xcworkspace XCode crashed, but other project worked fine. What I did is opened the xcworkspace file by right click and selecting Show Package Contents, then from that, inside  xcuserdata folder I deleted all folders, also emptied the Trash. It solved my problem.
OS: Catalina and XCode: 10.3

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to reinstall Xcode? Don't look to install the beta version. Instead install the regular released version.

Comment: I uninstalled the beta version and the one in the app store and tried to install it but did not solve the solution

Answer (score 0):

Find the stuff for your project in `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/` and trash it. Then restart your computer.

Open your project again with xcode